# Ordering not working in JQuery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I have a datatable being drawn on a page with an AJAX call.
I need to order the contents such that by default the latest entry is at the top. But even though the parameters have been changed there seems to be no change in the ordering at all and the records are listed at random.

```
var InitiateViewOption = null;
var deviceId = null;
var deviceType = null;
var fromTime = null;
var toTime = null;
var keys = null;

function drawTable(from, to) {
    var device = $("#device-details");
    deviceId = device.data("deviceid");
    deviceType = device.data("devicetype");
    keys = device.data("attributes").split(",");
    fromTime = from * 1000;
    toTime = to * 1000;
    if ( $.fn.dataTable.isDataTable( '#stats-table' ) ) {
        var table = $('#stats-table').DataTable();
        table.clear().draw();
        table.ajax.reload();
    }
    else {
        $("#stats-table").datatables_extended({
            serverSide: true,
            processing: true,
            searching: false,
            ordering: true,
            pageLength: 100,
            order: [[ 0, 'desc' ]],
            ajax: {
                url: "/devicemgt/api/stats/paginate",
                data: buildAjaxData
            }
        });
    }
}

function buildAjaxData (){
    var settings = $("#stats-table").dataTable().fnSettings();

    var obj = {
        //default params
        "draw" : settings.iDraw,
        "start" : settings._iDisplayStart,
        "length" : settings._iDisplayLength,
        "columns" : "",
        "order": "",
        "deviceType" : deviceType,
        "deviceId" : deviceId,
        "from": fromTime,
        "to"  : toTime,
        "attributes" : JSON.stringify(keys)
    };

    return obj;
}
```

Although making `ordering : true` does enable the icon near the table headers and the `order: [[ 0, 'desc' ]]` sets the icon according to the descending order there is no change in the actual order of the records with each new record being seemingly appended at random somewhere in the table.

[image]

Tried the `aaSorting : []` option according to the answer on [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41698560/sorting-is-not-working-in-jquery-datatables) as well but with no change

Comment: What is the request made to the server when you sort? You can open the dev tools in browser by pressing F12 then in the network tab clear all and check `disable cache` now click on the sort and see what request(s) are made. Maybe the JavaScript is fine but the api does not provide correctly sorted data.

Comment: Since you have `serverSide: true` you need to handle the ordering serverside as well.

Comment: @HMR I didn't realize that the data needed to be sorted on the server side as well, thanks for the suggestion I'll check into it.

Comment: @davidkonrad if the serverSide is kept as false would the ordering arranged according to the column and the ordering type that we state?

Comment: If your data is small enough to just fetch all of it once and then have the client do the paging, sorting, filtering ... then you could just fetch the data in a ajax and when that resolves set it to the data source of your datatable (`serverside:false`). Imagine your database having milions of rows it would be impossible to do the sorting, filtering, paging ... on the client, that's why `serverSide: true` does all of that on the server, not just fetching the first bit of data.

Comment: @nuwanjaya, Yes, if you have say less than 15.000 records, then you could just use AJAX without serverside. serverSide is meant as a solution for many rows, but have the down effect that you must take care of things like ordering yourself (or in the script, there is skeletons for most backend types) If you not explicitly set serverSide: true, then everything will be done clientside, with the dataset there is.

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:
Found out the reason behind the ordering not taking place. 
The issue was in the `.datatables_extended({` function.
Once I changed that to `.DataTable({` then made `serverSide: false` and then gave the columns for the ordering to take place it started working.